# What's the effect of two penalties directly following one another?

Tags: penalty

„I think the combination of age and the greater coming together is responsible for the speed of the passing time.“ (Sam Melville)

## What happens if penalties come together?

Let's say we have `\penalty\penalty` for some integers  and  in

1. text or
2. math

mode.

Can these two penalty instructions be viewed as a single `\penalty` for some integer ?  If so, how to express  as a function of  and ?  If not, what would be the best approximation of `\penalty\penalty` in terms of a single `\penalty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are not combined, so the smaller of the two penalties will be taken, a

The case of adjacent penalties is a question in the TeXBook:

```
\dangerexercise What happens if you say |\nobreak\break| or
|\break\nobreak|?
```

```
\answer You get a forced break as if\/ |\nobreak| were not present, because
|\break| cannot be cancelled by another penalty. In general if you
have two penalties in a row, their combined effect is the same as a single
penalty whose value is the minimum of the two original values, unless
both of those values force breaks. \ (You get two breaks from
|\break\break|; the second one creates an empty line.)
```

Comment: @AlbertNash as Knuth writes, it is the minimum unless both are <=-10000 in which case they both act. so `\penalty-10000\penalty-10000` is not the same as `\penalty min(-10000,-10000)` as that is `\penalty-10000`

Comment: Do you wish to say that `\penalty-10000\penalty-10000` forces TWO breaks? DEK's text only says that both values force breaks but doesn't specify whether these forced breaks are the same break (which is how I originally understood it) or distinct (that's what you said in your comment).

Comment: I wrote <= but ⩽ yes. DEK spells out explicitly you get two breaks in that case, see above: "You get two breaks"

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks!